# Open aspx page into a modal window and work with it

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to open a modal window when i click a button, inside the modal window should load an aspx page with controls and should work (make postbacks, etc).

how can i achive that ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way of doing this (if you don't need any value exchange between the parent and child window) is to use jquery dialog with an iFrame. Example:

```
        $("<iframe src='Modal.aspx'></iframe>").dialog({
        open: function () {
            // do something on open
        },
        // add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
        close: function (event, ui) {
            // remove div with all data and events
            dialog.remove();
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 300 },
        hide: { effect: 'fade', duration: 300 },
        title: "Modal Page Title goes here",
        buttons: //optional
        [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                click: function () {
                    dialog.remove();
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'OK',
                click: function () {
                    // do something on OK
                }
            }
        }).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `iframe` inside the modal you are displaying and load you aspx page inside the iframe.